# Country names from other country names

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am looking for 6 different country names

> 1 Take a country name and take out
>
> a number
>
> you will get another country name
>
> 2 Take a country name and take out
>
> three numbers
>
> you will get another country name
>
> 3 Take a country name and take out
>
> several numbers (not necessarily different)
>
> you will get another country name

No anagram of remaining letters needed.

No partial answers please. Some creative thinking needed.

Comment: I put the knowledge tag because not everyone knows all the country names

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Take out a number

> Australia -> Austria, by removing 'a L' or a 50

2. Take out three numbers

> Ireland -> Iran, by removing the three numbers e, L and D

3. Take out several numbers (not necessarily different)

> Indonesia -> India, by removing 'ones' which are several numbers

Comment: What is e as a number?

Comment: Perfectly done @Tom.

Comment: @Minot e is Euler's number

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Nigeria->Niger (IA is 26 in hex).
>  2. Australia->Austria (A is 10 in hex, L is 50 in Roman, I is 1 in Roman).
>  3. Indonesia->India (removing "ones").

Comment: You seem to be removing an extra 'i' in number 2.

Comment: Isn't 26 = 1A and not IA? If so, you are then converting I to 1 also? Just for clarification.

Comment: 1A. Second answer is incorrect anyway...